# Generating a PDF using Google Docs API

Tags: html, css, pdf, google-docs

Is it possible to provide HTML for the Google Docs API and have it output as a PDF? As far as I can tell, it seems like it is possible to submit an HTML document to Google Docs, and then have Google Docs convert it to a PDF.

I'm checking the API documentation and it has a lot of information about dealing with PDFs already created, but I'm not seeing anything about creating them.

Also, does it accept CSS styling as well, or is it pure HTML?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is, with two requests. You can import the file as a Google Docs, then export it to PDF. Using the Drive API.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get

this is what your saying right?

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16338468/3341400 . This might come useful for what you are looking for.

Comment: I think this user might be looking for https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/export in addition or instead?