# Apply CSS to HTML with Google Drive API (along with conversion to PDF)

Tags: html, css, pdf, google-drive-api

I notice that it is possible to convert HTML to a PDF using the Google Drive API [HTML2PDF using Google Drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843913/html2pdf-using-google-drive-api)

My question is whether it is possible to apply CSS to this HTML document that is then converted over to a PDF - is this a standard operation or is there anyway to support this? In short, does the document conversion of Google Drive recognize and parse CSS data, and how does it do so? How would I pass this as an argument?

I'm not seeing any API documentation on it at all.

Comment: have you tried it with inline css (`style=""` attribute) or a `<style>` element within the html?

Comment: Yes, but not all of my styles are being applied.

Comment: If you're looking to use Drive as a poor man's HTML to PDF converter, you're probably going to be disappointed. The conversion to/from Docs format is very lossy.